# How to import values from Json Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, random

i stored 3 twitter Api Keys in a Json file

```
{
  "twitter_api": [
    {
      "consumer_key":        "KEY",
      "consumer_secret":     "KEY",
      "access_token_key":    "KEY",
      "access_token_secret": "KEY"
    },
    {
      "consumer_key":        "KEY",
      "consumer_secret":     "KEY",
      "access_token_key":    "KEY",
      "access_token_secret": "KEY"
    },
    {
      "consumer_key":        "KEY",
      "consumer_secret":     "KEY",
      "access_token_key":    "KEY",
      "access_token_secret": "KEY"
    }
```

Everytime i run my twitter application i want to Import 1 set of api keys randomly.
i tried this code

```
var credentials = require('../settings.json').twitter_api[Math.floor(Math.random()*twitter_api.length)];
```

But i am getting an Error

anyone know how to do that correctly

Comment: Yes, Please specify the error

Comment: i am getting this Error : ReferenceError: twitter_api is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting `twitter_api is not defined` as its not defined at `twitter_api.length`.

Following will help

```
var twitter_api= require('../settings.json').twitter_api;

var credentials = twitter_api[Math.floor(Math.random()*twitter_api.length)];
```